# Sending json array via Alamofire

Tags: swift, alamofire

I wonder if it's possible to directly send an array (not wrapped in a dictionary) in a POST request. Apparently the `parameters` parameter should get a map of: [String: AnyObject]?
But I want to be able to send the following example json:

```
[
    "06786984572365",
    "06644857247565",
    "06649998782227"
]
```

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You can just encode the JSON with `NSJSONSerialization` and then build the `NSURLRequest` yourself. For example, in Swift 3:

```
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

let values = ["06786984572365", "06644857247565", "06649998782227"]

request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: values)

AF.request(request)                               // Or `Alamofire.request(request)` in prior versions of Alamofire
    .responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
            
            if let data = response.data, let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print(responseString)
            }
        case .success(let responseObject):
            print(responseObject)
        }
}
```

For Swift 2, see [previous revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27027253/5) of this answer.

Comment: @Rob I am getting the error like Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.} Any idea?

Comment: @NikunjJadav The response is not JSON. You might want to look at `response.data` (see revised answer above) to see what precisely the web service returned. Often there's a narrative description regarding the nature of the problem.

Comment: @Rob great answer thank you so much, but in my case what if the method is .get instead of .post?

Comment: With `GET` request, there's no body and parameters are supplied in `x-www-form-urlencoded` key-value pairs.  The most logical solution is to supply a key-value pair where the value is an array: `AF.request("https://robertmryan.com/privatetest/form/results.php", method: .get, parameters: ["stooges": ["moe", "larry", "curly"]])`. You would retrieve the array of names using the key, e.g. `$_GET['stooges']` or `$_REQUEST['stooges']`.

Answer (score 68):

For swift 3 and Alamofire 4 I use the following `ParametersEncoding` and `Array` extension:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire

private let arrayParametersKey = "arrayParametersKey"

/// Extenstion that allows an array be sent as a request parameters
extension Array {
    /// Convert the receiver array to a `Parameters` object. 
    func asParameters() -> Parameters {
        return [arrayParametersKey: self]
    }
}


/// Convert the parameters into a json array, and it is added as the request body. 
/// The array must be sent as parameters using its `asParameters` method.
public struct ArrayEncoding: ParameterEncoding {

    /// The options for writing the parameters as JSON data.
    public let options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions


    /// Creates a new instance of the encoding using the given options
    ///
    /// - parameter options: The options used to encode the json. Default is `[]`
    ///
    /// - returns: The new instance
    public init(options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions = []) {
        self.options = options
    }

    public func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
        var urlRequest = try urlRequest.asURLRequest()

        guard let parameters = parameters,
            let array = parameters[arrayParametersKey] else {
                return urlRequest
        }

        do {
            let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: array, options: options)

            if urlRequest.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") == nil {
                urlRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            }

            urlRequest.httpBody = data

        } catch {
            throw AFError.parameterEncodingFailed(reason: .jsonEncodingFailed(error: error))
        }

        return urlRequest
    }
}
```

Basically, it converts the array to a `Dictionary` in order to be accepted as `Parameters` argument, and then it takes back the array from the dictionary, convert it to JSON `Data` and adds it as the request body.

Once you have it, you can create request this way:

```
let values = ["06786984572365", "06644857247565", "06649998782227"]
Alamofire.request(url,
                  method: .post,
                  parameters: values.asParameters(),
                  encoding: ArrayEncoding())
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of encoding an Array of type Thing to JSON, using a router, and Ogra to do the JSON encoding:

```
import Foundation
import Alamofire
import Orga

class Thing {
    ...
}

enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {
    static let baseURLString = "http://www.example.com"

    case UploadThings([Thing])

    private var method: Alamofire.Method {
        switch self {
        case .UploadThings:
            return .POST
        }
    }

    private var path: String {
        switch self {
        case .UploadThings:
            return "upload/things"
        }
    }

    var URLRequest: NSMutableURLRequest {
        let r = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: Router.baseURLString)!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(path))
        r.HTTPMethod = method.rawValue

        switch self {
        case .UploadThings(let things):
            let custom: (URLRequestConvertible, [String:AnyObject]?) -> (NSMutableURLRequest, NSError?) = {
                (convertible, parameters) in
                var mutableRequest = convertible.URLRequest.copy() as! NSMutableURLRequest
                do {
                    let jsonObject = things.encode().JSONObject()
                    let data = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(jsonObject, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
                    mutableRequest.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                    mutableRequest.HTTPBody = data
                    return (mutableRequest, nil)
                } catch let error as NSError {
                    return (mutableRequest, error)
                }
            }
            return ParameterEncoding.Custom(custom).encode(r, parameters: nil).0
        default:
            return r
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 2.0**
This code below post object array.This code is tested on swift 2.0

```
func POST(RequestURL: String,postData:[AnyObject]?,successHandler: (String) -> (),failureHandler: (String) -> ()) -> () {

        print("POST : \(RequestURL)")

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string:RequestURL)!)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        var error: NSError?
        do {
             request.HTTPBody  = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(postData!, options:[])


        } catch {
            print("JSON serialization failed:  \(error)")
        }

        Alamofire.request(request)
            .responseString{ response in
                switch response.result {
                case .Success:
                    print(response.response?.statusCode)
                    print(response.description)
                    if response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
                        successHandler(response.result.value!)
                    }else{
                        failureHandler("\(response.description)")
                    }

                case .Failure(let error):
                    failureHandler("\(error)")
                }
        }

    }
```

Comment: i am getting error while calling a method.
  POST(baseUrl+WS_LOGIN, postData: jsonObject as a, successHandler: <#T##(String) -> ()#>, failureHandler: <#T##(String) -> ()#>)

what should i use in handler

Comment: Argument type 'NSMutableURLRequest' does not conform to expected type 'URLRequestConvertible'

Answer (score 0):

@manueGE 's answer is right. I have a similar approach according to alamofire github's instruction: 
`

```
struct JSONDocumentArrayEncoding: ParameterEncoding {
    private let array: [Any]
    init(array:[Any]) {
        self.array = array
    }
    func encode(_ urlRequest: URLRequestConvertible, with parameters: Parameters?) throws -> URLRequest {
        var urlRequest = urlRequest.urlRequest

        let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: array, options: [])

        if urlRequest!.value(forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") == nil {
            urlRequest!.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        }

        urlRequest!.httpBody = data

        return urlRequest!
    }
}
```

` 
Then call this by customize a request instead of using the default one with parameter. Basically discard the parameter, since it is a dictionary.

```
let headers = getHeaders()
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: (ServerURL + Api))!)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "post"
    urlRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    let jsonArrayencoding = JSONDocumentArrayEncoding(array: documents)

    let jsonAryEncodedRequest = try? jsonArrayencoding.encode(urlRequest, with: nil)

    request = customAlamofireManager.request(jsonAryEncodedRequest!)
    request?.validate{request, response, data in
        return .success
        }
        .responseJSON { /*[unowned self] */(response) -> Void in
            ...
    }
```

Also, the way to handle error in data is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
let url = try Router.baseURL.asURL()

// Make Request
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url.appendingPathComponent(path))
urlRequest.httpMethod = "post"

// let dictArray: [[String: Any]] = []
urlRequest = try! JSONEncoding.default.encode(urlRequest, withJSONObject: dictArray)
```

Something I do in my project to upload a JSON array

Answer (score 0):

```
  func placeOrderApi(getUserId:String,getDateId:String,getTimeID:String,getAddressId:String,getCoupon:String)
            {
                let data = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self.arrOfServices, options: [])
                let jsonBatch : String = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
                
                //try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: values)
               let params = [
                   "user_id":getUserId,
                   "time_id":getTimeID,
                   "date_id":getDateId,
                   "address_id":getAddressId,
                   "services":jsonBatch,
                   "payment_mode":paymentVia,
                   "coupon":getCoupon
                ] as [String : Any]
               
               print(params)
               self.objHudShow()
                
                Alamofire.request(BaseViewController.API_URL + "place_order", method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
                    .responseJSON { response in
                        debugPrint(response)
               
                    
                    switch response.result {
                        
                    case .success (let data):
                        print(data)
                                
                    self.objHudHide()
                    if response.result.value != nil
                    {
                       
                        let json : JSON = JSON(response.result.value!)
                       
                         if json["status"] == true
                         {
                           
                         }
                          else
                         {
                            self.view.makeToast(NSLocalizedString(json["msg"].string ?? "", comment: ""), duration: 3.0, position: .bottom)
                          }
                     
                             
                    }
                               
                        break
                                
                    case .failure:
                               self.objHudHide()
                               
                               print("Error in upload:)")
                                break
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 approach to send send JSON content as parameter.

1. You can send json as string and your web service will parse it on server.

   ```
    d["completionDetail"] = "[{"YearOfCompletion":"14/03/2017","Completed":true}]"
   ```
2. You can pass each value within your json (`YearOfCompletion` and `Completed`) in form of sequential array. And your web service will insert that data in same sequence. Syntax for this will look a like

   ```
   d["YearOfCompletion[0]"] = "1998"  
   d["YearOfCompletion[1]"] = "1997"  
   d["YearOfCompletion[2]"] = "1996"  

   d["Completed[0]"] = "true"  
   d["Completed[1]"] = "false"  
   d["Completed[2]"] = "true"
   ```

I have been using following web service call function with dictionary, to trigger `Alamofire` request **Swift3.0**.

```
func wsDataRequest(url:String, parameters:Dictionary<String, Any>) {
    debugPrint("Request:", url, parameters as NSDictionary, separator: "\n")

    //check for internete collection, if not availabale, don;t move forword
    if Rechability.connectedToNetwork() == false {SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: NSLocalizedString("No Network available! Please check your connection and try again later.", comment: "")); return}

    //
    self.request = Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: parameters)
    if let request = self.request as? DataRequest {
        request.responseString { response in
            var serializedData : Any? = nil
            var message = NSLocalizedString("Success!", comment: "")//MUST BE CHANGED TO RELEVANT RESPONSES

            //check content availability and produce serializable response
            if response.result.isSuccess == true {
                do {
                    serializedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)
                    //print(serializedData as! NSDictionary)
                    //debugPrint(message, "Response Dictionary:", serializedData ?? "Data could not be serialized", separator: "\n")
                }catch{
                    message = NSLocalizedString("Webservice Response error!", comment: "")
                    var string = String.init(data: response.data!, encoding: .utf8) as String!

                    //TO check when html coms as prefix of JSON, this is hack mush be fixed on web end. 
                    do {
                        if let index = string?.characters.index(of: "{") {
                            if let s = string?.substring(from: index) {
                                if let data = s.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8) {
                                    serializedData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)
                                    debugPrint(message, "Courtesy SUME:", serializedData ?? "Data could not be serialized", separator: "\n")
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }catch{debugPrint(message, error.localizedDescription, "Respone String:", string ?? "No respone value.", separator: "\n")}

                    //let index: Int = text.distance(from: text.startIndex, to: range.lowerBound)
                    debugPrint(message, error.localizedDescription, "Respone String:", string ?? "No respone value.", separator: "\n")
                }

                //call finised response in all cases
                self.delegate?.finished(succes: response.result.isSuccess, and: serializedData, message: message)
            }else{
                if self.retryCounter < 1 {//this happens really frequntly so in that case this fn being called again as a retry
                    self.wsDataRequest(url: url, parameters: parameters)
                }else{
                    message = response.error?.localizedDescription ?? (NSLocalizedString("No network", comment: "")+"!")
                    SVProgressHUD.showError(withStatus: message);//this will show errror and hide Hud
                    debugPrint(message)

                    //call finised response in all cases
                    self.delay(2.0, closure: {self.delegate?.finished(succes: response.result.isSuccess, and: serializedData, message:message)})
                }
                self.retryCounter += 1
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -11):

I think based on Alamofire documentation you can write the code as following:

```
let values = ["06786984572365", "06644857247565", "06649998782227"]

Alamofire.request(.POST, url, parameters: values, encoding:.JSON)
    .authenticate(user: userid, password: password)
    .responseJSON { (request, response, responseObject, error) in
        // do whatever you want here

        if responseObject == nil {
            println(error)
        } else {
            println(responseObject)
        }
}
```

Comment: No, the `parameters` is a `[String: AnyObject]?`. You cannot pass it an array. It must be a dictionary. Hence the question.

Comment: This answer would be true, if you pass a dictionary object rather than an array. encoding parameter will handle the rest.