# Alamofire POST JSON ARRAY

Tags: json, swift, post, request, alamofire

Alamofire - SWIFT JSON ARRAY

I want to Pass JSON ARRAY like this -

```
[
   {
      "OrgId": 1001,
      "ClassworkId": 999800580,
   }, {
      "OrgId": 1001,
      "ClassworkId": 0,
   }
]
```

I am Using this Method - I want to solve parameter - [String : AnyObject] -> Array

```
func delateClasswork (parameters: [String: AnyObject],completion: (success : Bool) -> Void) {
    request(.POST, "strURL", parameters: parameters, encoding:.JSON).responseJSON {
    response in switch response.result {
       case .Success(let JSON):
       if((JSON.valueForKey("StatusId")) as! NSNumber == 1){
           completion(success: true)
           break
       }else{
           completion(success: true)
           break
       }
       case .Failure(let error):
           completion(success : false)
           break
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: Check this one http://stackoverflow.com/a/27027253/6433023

Comment: I deleted my answer due to uncertainty. Add more details to your question.

Comment: Do you want to Send data or Parse the data received from server?

Answer (score 1):

Assign the whole data to one parameter `data`, this will maintain the Type to `[String:AnyObject]`.

```
let parameters:[String:AnyObject] = [
    "data" : [
        [
            "OrgId": 1001,
            "ClassworkId": 999800580,
        ],
        [
            "OrgId": 1001,
            "ClassworkId": 0,
        ]
    ]
]
```

At the server end you have to parse the data using `data` key.