# Adding [[String:AnyObject]] as parameter on Alamofire call (Swift 2)

Tags: json, swift, nsdictionary, alamofire, swifty-json

I have this JSON (this is a simplified version):

```
{
   "from":0,
   "location": [{
       "city":"Barcelona"
       }]
}
```

And i'm trying to do an Alamofire request with this JSON on parameters. So I have typed something like this:

```
let parameter = [
  "from":0,
  "location": [
   ["city": "Barcelona"] 
  ]
]
```

But it seems Alamofire doesn't accept the parse from [{ }]  to [[]] on parameters. I have read that one way to solve this is using a MutableURLRequest but i don't find any clear example.

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://myurl", parameters: (params as! [String : AnyObject]), headers: nil).responseCollection { (response: Response<[Group], NSError>) in
switch response.result {
            case .Success(let groups):
                print("Success")
            case .Failure(_):
                print("Failure")
            }
        }
```

This code above works and I get a result from this Alamofire Request but ignores this:

```
"location": [ ["city": "Barcelona"]]
```

Could someone can help with that? Thank you so much.

Comment: May be this will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026916/sending-json-array-via-alamofire

Comment: I get this error with this code @NiravD:

Comment: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1017 "no se puede analizar la respuesta" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x7fcacfa367a0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1017 "(null)" UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-1, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=4}}