# How to send single object as a parameter with Alamofire

Tags: ios, json, swift, parameters, alamofire

I've stuck with a problem I didn't imagine could happen.
I need to make a post request for the third-party API which allows only this

```
let parameters: Parameters = [{
        "id": "1",
        "original-address": "Some city, Some street"}]
```

As you can see it is not a dictionary, so compiler says `Cannot convert value of type '[() -> String]' to specified type 'Parameters' (aka 'Dictionary<String, Any>')`

I could not remove the brackets because my 3rd party API will not respond to this request.

How can I send such a request with Alamofire?

I've tried some suggestions from our beloved Stackoverflow, but still no luck.

Comment: `Alamofire is arguing` what do you even mean by this? Did you try removing the brackets?

Comment: @EmilioPelaez I mean compiler throws the error with description
`Cannot convert value of type '[() -> String]' to specified type 'Parameters' (aka 'Dictionary<String, Any>')` 
I could not remove the brackets because my 3rd party API will not respond to this request.

Answer (score 0):

`Parameters`  is a `typealias` for `[String:Any]` and you assign

```
[{
    "id": "1",
    "original-address": "Some city, Some street"}]
```

which looks like json array of dictionaries ( Not even swift array of Dics ) , so you can't pass it to `Alamofire`  , to accomplish what you need send it in the request body as `Data` look to [Sending json array via Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27026916/sending-json-array-via-alamofire)