# Array put request with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to make a put request with Alamofire and I want to pass in body something like this:

```
[
   {
    "id" : 1,
    "position": 0
   },
   {
    "id" : 2,
    "position": 1
   },
   {
    "id" : 6,
    "position": 2
   }
]
```

Normally, to do a request with alamofire I do this:

```
request = Alamofire
                .request(
                    url,
                    method: method,
                    parameters: parameters,
                    encoding: encoding,
                    headers: buildHeaders());
```

Alamofire forces me to make parameters a dictionary but I want that paramaters to be an array of dictonary. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Here the solution you are looking for 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27027253/9321469

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alamofire added support for `Encodable` parameters in Alamofire 5, which provides support for `Array` parameters. Updating to that version will let you use `Array` parameters directly. This support should be automatic when passing `Array` parameters, you just need to make sure to use the version of `request` using `encoder` rather than `encoding` if you're customizing the encoding.

Comment: it will be better to show some code example

Answer (score 1):

Well, the body of your parameters has type as [[String: Any]], or if you using Alamofire [Parameters].

So you if you parsing some Array of Objects to create this Array of parameters. You can do like this:

```
var positionedArray = [[String : Any]]()
        for (index, item) in dataArray.enumerated() {
            guard let id = item.id else {
                return
            }
            let singleParameters : [String: Any] = ["id": id, "position" : index]
            sorted.append(singleParameters)
        }
```

As result, you can use this body (parameters), for your request.
Also, you should use JSONSerialization:

For example, if you using a customized Alamofire client, just use extension:

```
let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
                let json = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                request.httpBody = json!.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                var finalRequest = try URLEncoding.default.encode(request, with: nil)
```